# Is there an Office 2010 registry key to turn on spellcheck by default?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office, spellcheck

I'm trying to figure out how to turn on spell check for all users automatically.

I'm hoping for a registry edit as I'm going to be making a win7x64 image with office 2010 pre installed and I don't feel like turning on spell-check manually on every deployment.

Comment: If these computers are memebrs of an AD domain you can configure spellcheck via GPO. You'll need to download and "install" the Office 2010 ADM/ADMX templates.

Comment: I might be missing something but shouldn't spell check be turned on by default? It is on my machine (Windows 8 x64 and Office 2010) and I never had to turn it on!

Answer (score 0):

As `joeqwerty` said, spellcheck could be configured via GPO, but what if computer is not a member of AD domain?

I can suggest you to download and run [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (procmon) from SysInternals (now Microsoft) and see for yourself which registry keys are written when spell checking settings are changed.